# CakePHP how to assign database connection dynamically

Tags: php, cakephp, configuration, constants

I have this constant value called CLIENT_URL

on boostrap:

```
$clienturl = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
define("CLIENT_URL",$clienturl[2]);
```

I've debugged and it gets, for example, 'client1', or 'client2', etc.
I need to use that value when defining a configuration array, such as:

on database.php

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

var $default = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => '*****',
    'password' => '****',
    'database' => 'client3',
    'prefix' => ''
 );    

var $clientdb = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => '****',
    'password' => '****',
    'database' => 'client3',
    'prefix' => ''
);

public function __construct() {
    debug('constant value: '.CLIENT_URL);
    debug($this->default['database']); 
    $this->default['database'] = CLIENT_URL; // This line does nothing !!
    //$this->clientdb['database'] = CLIENT_URL; // This lines prevent connection, error: Database connection "Mysql" is missing, or could not be created !!
    $this->default = $this->clientdb;
    debug($this->default['database']); 

}
};
```

However, database remains unchanged, it keeps initial value from above.
Actually i can do:

```
$this->default['database'] = 'whatever';
```

and it won't even try to find 'whatever' database; it seems this assignment is missing some reload or something?

After the assignment on __construct,

I've debugged

```
debug($this->default['database']);
```

Before and after the assignment and it does not change.
It only changes doing this:

```
$this->clientdb['database'] = CLIENT_URL; // Instead of $this->default['database'] = CLIENT_URL;
```

But then connection fails.

Please note the app does connect to the database given at the very beginning ('client3'), it just don't switch.
I check database via a find, that always return same record from same database, no switch.

```
$options = array('conditions' => array('User.id' => 1));
$clientArray = $this->User->find('first', $options);
```

Thank you for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do like this

```
class DATABASE_CONFIG {

var $client1db = array(
    'datasource' => 'Database/Mysql',
    'persistent' => false,
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'login' => '*****',
    'password' => '*****',
    'database' => 'client1',    
    'prefix' => ''
);


public function __construct() {
    $this->default = $this->clientdb;
    $this->default['database'] = CLIENT_URL;
}

};
```

Comment: Thank you @Moyed Ansari. However, database remains unchanged, please see edit.

Comment: You can debug $this->default after last line to see the change. Secondly are you using the same connection ?

Comment: I've just debugged and it wont show changes; i have different databases to test for the record retrieved. Please see edit. What do you suggest? Thank you.

Comment: try to debug debug($this->default['database']);

Comment: Thanks. I've debugged $this->default['database'] before and after assignment and it stays the same. Please see edit. I'm running out of hope ;-(

Comment: $this->default['database'] = CLIENT_URL; // This line will come after     $this->default = $this->clientdb;